# Form keeps submitting use false return

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello everyone I'm new in here btw and I'm not too good in english so cmiiw

Let's go straight for it, so the form keeps submitting even using false return on **function cekIsi**, and this is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.form-radio').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        $('table.webform-grid').css('opacity', 0.6);
        $('table.webform-grid').parent().slideUp();
    })
    $('form.webform-client-form input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
        refreshGrid($(this), true);
    })
    $('form.webform-client-form input:submit[id=edit-next]').click(function() {
        cekIsi($(this), true);
    })
    $('form.webform-client-form input:submit[id=edit-previous]').click(function() {
        cekIsi($(this), true);
    })
    $('form.webform-client-form input:submit[id=edit-submit]').click(function() {
        cekIsi($(this), true);
    })
});
function cekIsi(cb, init) {
var submitme = true;
$('.webform-grid').each(function(){
    if ($(this).css('opacity') == 1) {
     $(':radio', this).each(function() {
         nam = $(this).attr('name'); 
        if (submitme && !$(':radio[name="'+nam+'"]:checked').length) { 
        submitme = false;
        }
     });
 }
});

if(submitme == false && $('#edit-details-page-num').val() != 1){
    alert("Please stahp here");
    return false;
}
return true;
}
function refreshGrid(cb, init) {
    var xtable = $('table.webform-grid', $(cb).parents('fieldset.webform-component-fieldset'));
    if($(cb).attr('checked')) {
        $('input.form-radio', $(xtable)).each(function() {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        });
        $(xtable).css('opacity', 1);
        $(xtable).parent().slideDown();
    } else {
        $('tr', $(xtable)).each(function() {
            $('td input.form-radio' ,$(this)).attr('checked', false);
        });
        $('input.form-radio', $(xtable)).each(function() {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        });
        $(xtable).css('opacity', 0.6);
        $(xtable).parent().slideUp();
    }       
}
```

And this is the html code

```
<form action="/ict/ics/survey1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="site-switch-form">
<input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-next" value="Next Page >" class="form-submit">
```

So i'm begging you all give me good explanation why the false return is not working and how am I supposed to fix because I'm very new in javascript and jQuery..Thankyou thankyou very much

Comment: You can use `<input type="button">` instead of `<input type="submit">` then subimt the form via `javascript` with `form.subimt()`.

Comment: You need to write event.preventDefault(); if it returns false from your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event handling function is calling another function.

To stop the event, `false` must be returned by the event handler itself.

i.e. in your case instead of

`cekIsi($(this), true);`

try

`return cekIsi($(this), true);`

Also see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/pbosakov/m67rL5hb/

Answer (score 3):

The event handler is not returning false, only the function it calls returns false... Also, I suggest you use proper event handling instead of relying on just return false.

```
$('form.webform-client-form input:submit[id=edit-submit]').click(function(e) {
    cekIsi($(this), true);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
})
```

With `e.preventDefault();` it prevents the default behavior of the click, here it stops the click from submitting the form.

Comment: Also, it's been a while, but does input:submit really targets submit inputs? Wouldn't it be input[type=submit] ?

Answer (score 1):

You have added "return false;" inside cekIsi(). cekIsi() will return false. Submit is an event. You need to use event.preventDefault(); initially and after it satisfies all the condition you need to submit your form $( "form" ).submit();

Answer (score 0):

On your form submit event call back  prevent default functionality of the sublit event

```
$('form#site-switch-form').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    // your code
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using preventdefault

```
$('form.webform-client-form input:submit[id=edit-next],form.webform-client-form input:submit[id=edit-previous],form.webform-client-form input:submit[id=edit-submit]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    cekIsi($(this), true);
});
```